# Zoom map to a location and move it to right

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming, move

I want to zoom GoogleMap to a location, which is shown as a marker, and after that, scroll that marker to the right by pixel,
Currently I combine 2 actions above like this:

```
LatLng point = new LatLng(lat,lon);

MarkerOptions endMarker = new MarkerOptions().position(point);

googleMap.addMarker(endMarker);

googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(point, 15f));

int screenWidth = getScreenWidth();

int margin = (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.double_standard_margin_padding);

new Handler().postDelayed(() -> googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy(-(screenWidth - margin) * 3 / 8, 0), new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFinish() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {

                    }
                }), 1000);
```

As you can see, I have added 2 methods to do it:

```
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(point, 15f));

googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy(-(screenWidth - margin) * 3 / 8, 0)
```

And I have to delay the action to move the map because we don't know when the map is zoomed

And sometimes the map could not move (onCancel()) so I can not receive the expected UI.

Could someone know how to archive it in only one way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced the same problem several times and I have created a `CameraUpdateAnimator` that executes a chain of `CameraUpdates` with a given delay (if needed) and allowing the camera to be moved or animated (see [my project on GitHub](https://github.com/antoniocarlon/MapUtils/blob/master/src/map/CameraUpdateAnimator.java)). I think that it can be useful in your case:

```
CameraUpdateAnimator animator = new CameraUpdateAnimator(mMap, this); // Parameters: a GoogleMap instance and an OnCameraIdleListener to return the control to (can be null)
animator.add(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(point, 15f), false, 0); // Move the camera without delay
animator.add(CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy(-(screenWidth - margin) * 3 / 8, 0), true, 1000); // Animate the camera with a 1000 milliseconds delay
animator.execute();
```